# Create Container view for Two UIViewController on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

i have two UIViewController class with xib from interface builder, and i want create another UIViewController with xib that contains this two view, it's possible and how i can achieve this feature?

Comment: not sure bt 99% not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

You add two UIView in your third UIViewController xib and you link these UIView with IBOulet.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *firstView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *secondView;
```

After that you add your UIViewController in theses subviews in the viewDidLoad for example :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyFirstViewController *myFirstViewController = [[MyFirstViewController alloc] initWitNibName:@"MyFirstViewController"];
    MySecondViewController *mySecondViewController = [[MySecondViewController alloc] initWitNibName:@"MySecondViewController"];

    [self.firstView addSubview:myFirstViewController.view];
    [self.secondView addSubview:mySecondViewController.view];
}
```

Improve it with @property of First and Second ViewController and Lazy loading.

Comment: if i do like you say i receive a warning: "Incompatibile pointer types sending 'MyFirstViewController' to parameter of type 'UIView'

Comment: I forgot .view in addSubview

Answer (score 0):

You can't add View controller A and B's views to view controller C in an XIB because there is a fair amount of housekeeping code you need to do to set up the parent/child view controller relationship.

However, if you were to use storyboards, and you are running in iOS 6 or later, this would be trivial. There is a new "container" view in iOS 6. You just add a container view to your scene, and then control-drag from the container view onto another view controller's scene, and IB sets up an embed segue that does all the housekeeping for you. In my view this feature alone is enough to justify moving to storyboards.

Comment: Unfortunatley i doesn't use storyboards...can make it without it?